# MQL4 How To Detect Status During Change of Account (Completed Downloading of Historical Trades)

Tags: metatrader4, mql4

In MT4, there exists a stage/state: when we switch from AccountA to AccountB, when Connection is established and init() and start() are triggered by MT4; but before the "blinnnggg" (sound) when all the historical/outstanding trades are loaded from Server.

Switch Account>Establish Connection>Trigger Init()/Start() events>Start Downloading of Outstanding/Historical trades>Completed Downloading (issue "bliinng" sound).

I need to know (in MQL4) that all the trades are completed downloaded from the tradeServer --to know that the account is truly empty -vs- still downloading history from tradeServer.

Any pointer will be appreciated. I've explored `IsTradeAllowed()` `IsContextBusy()` and `IsConnected()`.  All these are in "normal" state and the init() and start() events are all fired ok. But I cannot figure out if the history/outstanding trade lists has completed downloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: The final workaround I finally implemented was to use the `OrdersHistoryTotal()`. Apparently this number will be ZERO (0) during downloading of order history.  And it will NEVER be zero (due to initial deposit). So, I ended-up using this as a "flag".

Comment: **A nice piece of logic, Joseph** +1. Hope the next release of "new"-MQL will not devastate this. Last week stopped another service feature that was working for several years right due to Build 840 field Update...

Answer (score 0):

### Observation

As the problem was posted, there seems no such "integrated" method for MT4-Terminal.

**`IsTradeAllowed()`** reflects an administrative state of the account/access to the execution of the Trading Services `{ IsTradeAllowed | !IsTradeAllowed }`

**`IsConnected()`** reflects a technical state of the visibility / login credentials / connection used upon an attempt to setup/maintain an online connection between a localhost <-> Server `{ IsConnected() | !IsConnected() }`

**`init() {...}`** is a one-stop setup facility, that is/was being called once an MT4-programme `{ ExpertAdvisor | Script | TechnicalIndicator }` was launched on a localhost machine. This facility is strongly advised to be non-blocking and non-re-entrant. A change from the user account_A to another user account_B is typically ( via an MT4-configuration options ) a reason to stop an execution of a previously loaded MQL4-code ( be it an EA / a Script / a Technical Indicator ) )

**`start() {...}`** is an event-handler facility, that endlessly waits, for a next occurrence of an FX-Market Event appearance ( being propagated down the line by the Broker MT4-Server automation ) that is being announced via an established connection downwards, to the MT4-Terminal process, being run on a localhost machine.

### A Workaround Solution

As understood, the problem may be detected and handled indirectly.

While the MT4 platform seems to have no direct method to distinguish between the complete / in-complete refresh of the list of `{ current | historical }` trades, let me propose a method of an indirect detection thereof.

Try to launch a "**signal**"-trade ( a pending order, placed geometrically well far away, in the PriceDOMAIN, from the current <kbd>Ask</kbd>/<kbd>Bid</kbd>-levels ).

Once this trade would be end-to-end registered ( Server-side acknowledged ), the local-side would have confirmed the valid state of the `db.POOL`

Making this a request/response pattern between localhost/MT4-Server processes, the localhost `int init(){...}` / `int start(){...}` functionality may thus reflect a moment, when the both sides have synchronised state of the records in `db.POOL`